# Why does /{usr-id}/feed return an empty result in Facebook API v2.4?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

**UPDATE**:
There must have been a caching issue (for the token/page). Now that I try I get a consistent response for both versions (empty list). Unless my friend also uses the app, it can't fetch their activities.

I'm testing in Graph explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), with a token that has user_status and user_post.
Calling `/v2.4/10153373299959566/feed?fields=id,message,picture,likes,shares,comments`
returns an empty list, while the same thing using v2.3 returns posts of that user.

Is there anything I'm missing?
I read the upgrade guide in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading but couldn't find anything.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does new API only return my own feed, and not my friends?

Comment: What access token are you using?

Comment: Graph explorer's, with the permissions shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Did that other user grant the app the same permissions before? In that case, it works fine for me in GAE.

Comment: No, the other user is a friend. I'm trying to read his posts. It works in 2.3, but not in 2.4. My posts (/me) works in both 2.3 and 2.4.

Comment: Which app are you using, the GAE app, or one of your own? (Via the dropdown on top of the page.)

Comment: Do you mean Facebook's graph explorer by GAE app? Does it run on GAE?

Comment: The dropdown is the little triangle you can see in the screenshot, near the version number.

Comment: No, I meant which app you are using – via the dropdown next to “Application:” in the top right corner.

Comment: Oh right, I selected Graph ApI Explorer there.

Comment: And the other user (who’s feed you are trying to read) granted those permissions to the Graph API Explorer app as well?

Comment: Well then you should not be able to read their posts at all.

Comment: With more testing I'm getting to that conclusion, which makes sense too. There might have been a caching issue when I tried it. Now I can't reproduce it at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CBroe.